# map = ((mapfragment) getfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyid(r.id.map)).getmap() Fatal Exception

Tags: nullpointerexception

Using Android Studio, I've been staring, poking and prodding at this application for hours. I'm stuck on a fatal exception at line 28:

**map = ((mapfragment) getfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyid(r.id.map)).getmap()**

I have no idea where it's going wrong at this point. I read something about null values, but I'd copied and pasted nearly all of the code from a previous one-activity Maps app that works flawlessly. My libraries are in working order, too. I need to get passed this part so I can move on to using a search feature with Google Places.

The app starts with a splash activity -> main menu -> map activity
Included are map.java, map.xml, and AndroidManifest.xml

map.java:

```
package com.LittleBlackApp.MaJoRProduct.littleblackapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class map extends Activity {
private final LatLng LOCATION_NAPLES = new LatLng(40.852758, 14.269437);
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick_btnNap(View v){
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_NAPLES, 9);
    map.animateCamera(update);

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

map.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".main">



<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Naples"
    android:id="@+id/btnNap"
    android:onClick="onClick_btnNap"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnNap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.LittleBlackApp.MaJoRProduct.littleblackapp" >

<users-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<permission
    android:name="com.LittleBlackApp.MaJoRProduct.littleblackapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.LittleBlackApp.MaJoRProduct.littleblackapp.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="NEW API KEY HERE"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".contact"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".map"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".chat"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ></activity>
    <activity android:name=".note"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DId you ever resolve this issue? I am also unable to initiate google maps. The funny thing is, I am receiving the null pointer erorr on the line of code I am instantiating the map! It works fine on API16+ devices, but devices below my application is crashing.